# python plotly (px) animation frame date is in wrong order

Tags: python, date, animation, plotly, plotly-express

With plotly express I've built a bar chart similar to as shown on their [website](https://plotly.com/python/animations/).

As px.bar did not allow me to run the animation frame on datetime64[ns] I transformed the datetime into a string as follows.

```
eu_vaccine_df['date_str'] = eu_vaccine_df['date'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
eu_vaccine_df[['date_str', 'date', 'country', 'people_vaccinated_per_hundred']].head()
```

The dataset on which I then run the px.bar looks as follows and contains 30 different countries.

[image: dataframe]

The code for my barchart including animation looks as follows.

```
fig = px.bar(
  eu_vaccine_df,
  x='country', y='people_vaccinated_per_hundred',
  color='country',
  animation_frame='date_str',
  animation_group='country',
  hover_name='country',
  range_y=[0,50],
  range_x=[0,30]
)
fig.update_layout(
  template='plotly_dark',
  margin=dict(r=10, t=25, b=40, l=60)
)
fig.show()
```

In the end result the date on the animation frame is wrong. It first shows all results from 2021 and then all results from 2020 as shown at the bottom of the following screenshot.
[image: wrong order of the years]

Comment: Hi Sebastian, do you mind to share a sample of the data?

Comment: As side note: you can convert date to string with `eu_vaccine_df['date'].astype('str')`. In case of big dataframes it's way faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting my df by the date solved the issue.

```
  covid_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid_df['date'])
  covid_df = covid_df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
  covid_df['date'] = covid_df['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```